# Buying Paris metro tickets from Eurostar before/during the journey?

Tags: public-transport, france, uk, high-speed-rail, eurostar

Whenever a Eurostar gets into Brussels, and especially when one gets into Paris, there is always a mad scramble for the metro ticket machines, and if you weren't in the first coach then a very long queue...

A couple of years ago I did manage to buy Paris metro tickets from the [Eurostar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurostar) information desk in London before I left, as described [here](http://www.seat61.com/Paris-metro.htm). (It was at the information desk on the far right after security and passport checks). I seem to recall they even sold me the tickets in sterling at the day's exchange rate!

I've subsequently recommended this to a friend, who wasn't able to buy the tickets from the information desk, and instead had the long queue at the metro ticket machines on arrival.

Does anyone know if Eurostar are still normally selling metro tickets from the information counter? And/or does the buffet on board sell them? (I think I've once heard an announcement about that)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I do recall Paris metro tickets being available on the Eurostar and at the information desk in London, but that was a few years ago and may well no longer be true. The price is rather more expensive than if you get them in Paris.

There generally isn't that much of a queue in Paris Nord, especially outside peak hour. This is one of Paris's busiest stations and one Eurostar isn't that much of a load. Most travelers head for the most visible ticket selling machines, but there are many machines in different corners of the station. Head to the far end of the platform (where the suburban services leave; suburban ticket selling machines, such as the one pictured on [Seat 61](http://www.seat61.com/Paris-metro.htm), sell metro tickets as well). Or head downstairs into the metro/RER area, and spread out a little; that's often enough not to have to queue much if at all.

Comment: As suggested, I turned left off the Eurostar and headed towards the suburban platforms, and got metro tickets from a Green ticket machine without problems, no queue either!

Answer (score 12):

You can buy a single ticket or a carnet of 10 tickets from the buffet.

In 2013 there was a markup of around 10-20% and they only had carnets available.

As of September 2015, the markup was around 50% (£15 @ 1.37EUR/pound, compared to €14.10 in Paris). They were also selling single tickets at about a 20% markup (£1.60 each - €1.80 in Paris).

They sometimes mention the availability of the tickets in the PA announcements on the train.

Sources: my own experience (March/April 2011, September 2015), discussion in the comments, [this webpage](http://www.about-paris.com/eurostar_london_to_paris.htm)

Comment: Were you limited to buying a carnet of 10, or did they do individual tickets too?

Comment: Not certain - a carnet was what I wanted anyway.

Comment: I've just bought some on board - only carnets of 10 available, no single ones. It's currently €14.90 or £11.80 for a carnet of 10

Comment: @Gagravarr In that case information that they are over-priced should be added to the post. Current price in Parisian ticket machines is EUR 13.30 for a carnet of 10.

Comment: I've incorporated the extra information from these comments into my post.